# Ruby Soap Error; logged in, but getting not logged in error

Tags: ruby, soap

So I'm creating an API script in ruby for Bluecat(IPAM). I'm having no problem logging on, but when I try to run an add IPv4 command I get this error:

```
in `raise_soap_and_http_errors!': (env:Server) Not logged in (Savon::SOAPFault)
```

my script (with some extra code taken out) is below:

```
require 'savon'
require 'csv'

module Bluecat
class Api

WsdlUrl = 'http:/bluecat/Services/API?wsdl'
User = 'username'
Pass = 'password'

attr_accessor :auth_cookies
attr_accessor :client
def initialize
  @client = Savon.client(wsdl: WsdlUrl)
  unless client.nil?
    login
    puts client.operations
    addIP4Network
  else
    print "No client\n"
  end
  print "Got cookies %s\n" % auth_cookies
  logout
end

def login
  response = client.call(:login) do
    message username: User, password: Pass
  end
  @auth_cookies = response.http.cookies
end

def logout
  puts "logging out"
  client.call(:logout)
end

def addIP4Network
  CSV.foreach('CSV', :headers => true , :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1') do |row,i|

    message = {'blockId' => 'example' , 'CIDR' => row[0] , 'properties' => "configuration = COV "}
    response = client.call(:add_ip4_network, message: message)

  end
end
end
end
```

Any ideas as to why I am getting this error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  Apparently, you need to send the cookies with every request.

Change

```
response = client.call(:add_ip4_network, message: message)
```

to

```
response = client.call(:add_ip4_network, message: message, cookies: auth_cookies)
```